# WebService EndPoint Not accessible in Jboss Fuse 6

Tags: web-services, osgi, cxf, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I developed Simple WebService OSGI Bundle with Eclipse Libra, Apache CXF and deployed it in JBoss Fuse 6. But when i tried to access it with http://x.x.x.x:8181/cxf/TestWs?wsdl it shows nothing.

I also tried following URL http://x.x.x.x:8181/cxf and it says no services.

I check status of this with karaf shell osgi:list and it shows me its Active.

Please let me know if i am doing any wrong?

Following is my Manifest.Mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: TestWs
Bundle-SymbolicName: TestWs
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes/
Export-Package: com.irk.ws,
com.irk.ws.jaxws
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: javax.el,
javax.servlet,
javax.servlet.http,
javax.servlet.jsp,
javax.servlet.jsp.el,
javax.servlet.jsp.tagext
Web-ContextPath: /TestWs
```

Regards,

Comment: Did you try `cxf:list-endpoints` and did you see your endpoint?

Comment: Can you show the spring xml file or endpoint configuration

Comment: I came across a similar issue detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200138/jboss-fuse-cxf-rs-rest-issue-no-services-have-been-found

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding camel-cxf feature ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.